# Libsodium - php asymmetric message encryption/decryption with only one key pair

Tags: php, public-key-encryption, libsodium

I would like to encrypt the message with libsodium library with recipient public_key without my private_key/public_key usage. Later recipient shall be able to decrypt it with his private_key.

Will it be possible with `crypto_box_keypair()` key pair generated for recipient?

Which function shall I use to for encryption and decryption?

I know this would be possible with openssl, but is it possible at all with libsodium?

Thanks.

Comment: it looks like ```crypto_box_seal()``` might be the answer here. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: what does your research tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose Sealed Box Encryption seems to be the best approach:

```
string \Sodium\crypto_box_seal(string $message, string $publickey)
```

This will encrypt a message with a user's public key, and then he will be able to decrypt it with his private key.
This however address only encryption need (which was the case in my question).